# IApplicationService in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I'm new to WPF and I'm actually migrating a project from Silverlight to WPF 4.0 and my problem is that I can't find the equivalence for **IApplicationService** and **IApplicationLifetimeAware**.

The library and namespace System.Windows is well loaded, yet I have the error message;
"The type or namespace name 'IApplicationLifetimeAware' could not be found'.

Any idea what am i missing please.

Thanks

Comment: Checking on MSDN, it looks like this is a Silverlight only interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iapplicationservice(v=vs.95).aspx

You may need to approach the solution differently for WPF.

Comment: System.Windows.Application looks like the WPF equivalent to IApplicationLifetimeAware - it exposes Startup, Exit, etc. events.  You can set your event handlers in the App.xaml root node.  I'm not sure if there's any analog to IApplicationService in WPF.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Samuel and Whyaduck.
But if I am to implement the IApplicationService and IApplicationLifetimeAware in a class, how do I do with System.Windows.Application? Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that there's no direct migration and all need to be recoded.
but if anyone is implementing `IApplicationService` and `IApplicationLifetimeAware` just to access the `StatService()`, you can simply make the method public, without argument..

```
public void StartService()
{
.
.
}
```

and call the method during instanciation in App.xaml.cs

```
 public App()
        {
            this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
            this.Exit += this.Application_Exit;

            InitializeComponent();

            OfflineDatabaseService x = new OfflineDatabaseService();
            x.StartService();
        }
```